# secure array list from de-compiling

Tags: android

I have 5M+ Download app but i facing a big problem. I use minifyEnabled true. One my competitor app use my all array list. And arrayList have a lot of information. Is there any way I can secure my arraylist from de-compiling? (I only want to secure my arraylist where I have lots of information written)

I told my developer but he has no solution

I used minifyEnabled true

Answer (score 0):

While minifyEnabled true helps obfuscate code, securing sensitive data in an ArrayList from determined reverse engineering is challenging. Consider encrypting the data, using advanced obfuscation, and offloading critical operations to a server. Additionally, explore legal options and consult with security experts for a more tailored solution.